# What could be the reason of linux pppd process failing in NCP negotiation with service provider during PPP?

Tags: linux, networking, bluetooth

I want to set up internet on my lapptop using mobile DUN profile.
But I am able to do PAP authentication and LCP negotiations but
pppd fails in NCP phase when it requests for IP address and dns.

what could be possible the reasons for it ?

Link to ppp script : 
http://pastebin.com/qBPw8Tb2

Link to connection log : 
http://pastebin.com/KVrUDafF

I think pppd is failing any of the following step of ipcp negoitaions:
1.ip negotiations of both end-points
2.dns address negotiation, 
3.tcp header compression technique negotiation.

Can anybody provide some inputs ?

Comment: Do you have a log of the connection attempt along with any messages that might indicate why it failed?

Comment: I have put log in pastebin. and I got error like kernel does not support ppp filtering..is it causing problem ?

Comment: I am using ppp version 2.4.4 .

Comment: It _looks_ like the remote device is not configured to pass out IP information.  Are you able to connect to this same device using another computer/os?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have remove the following  parameter from ppp scripts and it worked .

-novj
-novjccomp